# Using APEX_CUSTOM_AUTH.APPLICATION_PAGE_ITEM_EXISTS in external Package - APEX 21.2

Tags: oracle-apex

I have a page where the following page item, `:P10_ACCOUNT_CHANGED_FLAG`, is not always rendered on the page (using Server Side condition). I have an external package that references this page.

I am trying to check for the existence of the page item. If it exists, then set form value to a global package variable, `g_changed_flag` in the package. If not, then default value to `'N'`.

I was trying to use:

```
l_page_item_exists := apex_custom_auth.application_page_item_exists(:P10_ACCOUNT_CHANGES_FLAG);

if l_page_item_exists then
  g_change_flag := v('P10_ACCOUNT_CHANGES_FLAG');
else
  g_change_flag := 'N';
end if;
```

But it throws the following error:

```
PLS-00049: bad bind variable 'P10_ACCOUNT_CHANGES_FLAG'
```

Any advice?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

You're looking for an item, not its value.

Try

```
l_page_item_exists := 
  apex_custom_auth.application_page_item_exists('P10_ACCOUNT_CHANGES_FLAG');
```

instead.

Comment: As always, thanks @Littlefoot. This seems to work now. 
I misunderstood the documentation example then. https://docs.oracle.com/en/database/oracle/application-express/21.2/aeapi/APPLICATION_PAGE_ITEM_EXISTS-Function.html#GUID-7252D07F-C762-4894-B8C0-09284B62177F